# get POJO Class object from request in struts action class without OGNL

Tags: jsp, servlets, struts2

I have one jsp page, which pass all parameters like `user.userid`, `user.username`, `user.email` etc.. I am using struts 2 and want to get `user` object from request in action class. i don't want to use get set method with OGNL concept. i required that object from request only. is there any way to do that?

I have more than 100 parameters like this so i don't want to do `request.getParameter("user.userid")` for each parameter.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP requests send strings.

If you bypass the built-in mechanism for converting those strings to objects, you'll get strings, because that's all that's sent. If you want to reconstruct an object from strings on the server side then you'll have to do *something* equivalent, whether it's manual or by using another library.

When asking questions like this it's best to explain the "why". That gives people reading the question a rationale which may affect any advice given.